# Overlapping annotations in GATE

Tags: annotations, gate

I am trying to merge two annotations in a document and that works fine but I want to select only the annotations which are common to both of them e.g. one annotation highlights a sentence  "I am testing my grammar" and the second annotation highlights "testing my grammar". The second annotation also highlights "testing my grammar" at some other place but I dont want to pick that since its not highlighted by the first annotation.

I would like to figure out a way of picking up just the common part. I am using GATE 7.1 and have used normal PRs along with one Annotation Merging PR. Is there some way by which I can create a feature which somehow shows that both annotations have been used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a jape transducer with operator "within", described [here](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html#x12-2370008.2.4).

Here's a simple rule which will match only Ann2 (testing my ..) when it's within another annotation Ann1 (I am testing my ...)

```
Phase: phrase
Input: Ann1 Ann2
Options: control = appelt

Rule: ann2WithinAnn1
(
   ({Ann2 within Ann1})
):aa
--> :aa.Overlap = {}
```

Keep in mind that partial overlaps are harder to catch with jape (or at least I don't know how) for instance:

```
Ann1 on "I am testing".
Ann2 on "testing my grammar".
```

Comment: Thanks Yasen. I have it figured out now.

Comment: Accept the answer @user2910192 if its helpful